# Multiple Lines of Text Height Ignored

Tags: rich-text, multiple-lines-of-text, textarea

See screen-shots below:

- SharePoint is ignoring my setting for `Number of lines for editing` - what is going on here? It's seems somehow that the list has switched into a HTML style `textarea` all of a sudden.
- It's inserting a bunch of line-feeds
- It doesn't look like it's supporting `Enhanced Rich Text`- seems to be "stuck" on the cut-down Rich Text style.

[image]

[image]